# Extracting integer data from FireBase database query in Javascript

Tags: database, firebase, integer

I have this code:

```
function readValues() {
homeScoreRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
```

}

Which appears in the console as:

[image: Console Window]

Here is what the database looks like:

[image: Databse]

When I retrieve the data, all I want is the integer value, which in this case is 4. When I try to put that data into a Div, it shows up as "[object Object]". I just want the number. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `homeScoreRef` is probably pointing to `/scores` since it is returning an object with the `home` key/value. Point it to `/scores/home` and it should return the value of 4. In Firebase 3 it would look like this:

```
let homeScoreRef = firebase.database().ref('/scores/home');
homeScoreRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  // snapshot.val() should now be 4
});
```

In the older Firebase 2, it would look something like this:

```
let homeScoreRef = new Firebase('https://your-subdomain.firebaseio.com/scores/home');
homeScoreRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  // snapshot.val() should now be 4
});
```

Comment: Here is my initialization now:                                                                    var homeScoreRef = firebase.database().ref("scores/home");                           The div still displays [Object, object]

Comment: Can you show the code of where you are putting the result in a div?

Comment: I'm doing this on my phone so sorry if it doesn't show up well: function readValues() {
 homeScoreRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  HomeScoreDiv.innerHTML = snapshot.val();
 }, function (error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error.code);
 });

Comment: Lol, that's impressive! So I just tried it on a firebase project I had to double check my syntax and they look good. I did fix the paths in my answer, I was using `score` instead of `scores`. What does console.log(snapshot.val()); print out?

Comment: Heres what it prints out, Its in a tree, not on one line: Object>home: 4__proto__: Object

Comment: Figured it out. It looks similar to your code but with different syntax.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind posting what it was? It was baffling me!

Comment: function readValues() {
    homeScoreValueRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    HomeScoreDiv.innerHTML = snapshot.val();
    HomeScore = snapshot.val();
    });